# Sorting data by relevance, from multiple tables

Tags: algorithm, search, search-engine, relevance

How is it possible to sort data from multiple tables by relevance?

My table structure is following:
I have 3 tables in my database, one table contains the name of solar systems, the second for e.g. of planets. There is one more table, witch is a connection between solar systems and  planets.

If I want to get data of a planet, witch is in the Milky Way, i post this data to the server, and it gives me a multi-dimensional array witch contains:

1. The Milky Way, with every planet in it
2. Every planet, witch name contains the string Milky Way

(maybe thats a bat example because i don't think that theres but one planet with this name, but the main concept is on file)

But, i want to set the most relevant planets to the top of the array. (for the relevance i would check the description of the planets or something like that)

So, how would you do that kind of data sorting?

Comment: I prefer to do most of my dining out on earth.

Comment: This is the crux of any good search engine. It's why google is google. Now then, check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html and maybe concat the columns you want to search on together prior to the searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order by` in sql will order the results of your query by whatever field you want.  You could then use limit to only get the first N results.